# How to control selection from ViewModel of MultiSelectTreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, view-model-pattern

I've got a WPF MultiSelectTreeView (downloaded from here: http://unclassified.software/en/source/multiselecttreeview).

Now I want to control, which items the user selects. A simple example is that he shouldn't be able to select child nodes of different parents. But there are also more ViewModel-specific use cases.

It's easy to achieve this in code-behind of the Window by using the PreviewSelectionChanged event, checking the conditions directly and setting the Cancel-flag accordingly. But since I want to obtain the separation of View and ViewModel, I am looking for a way of doing this in my WindowViewModel.

Of course you could also extract the check to the ViewModel and call it from the view, but it looks wrong:

```
WindowViewModel _viewModel;

void PreviewSelectionChanged(object sender, PreviewSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     e.Cancel = !this._viewModel.CanSelect(e.Item as TreeItemViewModel);
}
```

I hope that anybody has an idea.

- timnot90

Comment: Separation of View / Logic does not mean no code behind in your view classes. You don't lose testability of your ViewModels by using PreviewSelectionChanged, so in my opinion it's fine.

Comment: Typically, your data items should have an `IsSelected` property that you data bind to the `TreeViewItem.IsSelected` property. Then you can just set that to `true` to select an item and to `false` to deselect an item.

Comment: @Sheridan
Yes they have. But I have no idea when to set this property. If I do it in  code behind, I can also do it the way I described in my question. 
And since it seems to be okay, I think I will. I just thought that there is some kind of fancy, extraordinary way of doing this in mvvm.

Thanks for your help.

Just one more thing: what can I do to mark this question as answered with no "real" answer available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, when data binding a hierarchical collection to a `TreeView` in WPF, the custom data items should have an `IsSelected` property defined in their class. If they do, then it can be data bound to the `IsSelected` property of each `TreeViewItem`:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}" ... >
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

When this is done, you can just set that property to `true` to select an item and to `false` to deselect an item.

```
// Select Item
dataObject.IsSelected = true;

// Deselect Item
dataObject.IsSelected = false;
```

You can add a handler to the `PropertyChanged` event of each item to detect when the `IsSelected` property changes (if they implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface as expected).

Comment: I implemented an IsSelectedChanged event in the ViewModel of the data items now and it's working perfectly. Thanks a lot.